# How to collide with a HEROIC FANTASY CREATURES FULL PACK from unity asset store

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, assets, rigid-bodies, mesh-collider

So I bought the unity humble bundle which had tons of great things for a very cheap price and one of them included the HEROIC FANTASY CREATURES FULL PACK VOLUME 1. I was messing around with it but I realized I had two problems. First is that I can not have gravity from a rigid body and a concave mesh so the mesh was sloppy. But the bigger issue is that the mesh doesn't change with the animation. I assume that the mesh won't change with the animation but I couldn't find anything that told me it wouldn't. If anyone can point me to a tutorial or discord or any help at all that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup custom colliders, preferably capsule colliders , for each joint. see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCWIl8WWJF0